# how to get setOnMyLocation button in fragment(map)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have Map in which i want gps symbol(when user click on this symbol it will take user to current location). I can do it in activity and it is working fine in activity but it is creating problem in Fragment.
**CASE 1** : If i writing the below code in `onCreateView` method then it is getting called before the `googleMap` is initialized that why i am getting Null Pointer Exception.

```
((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap)).getMapAsync(this);
if(googleMap!=null){
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            if(marker!=null){
                marker.remove();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap=googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
    Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
}
```

**CASE 2** If i am writing this in `onMapready` then it is taking me to the current location automatically even without clicking on it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap=googleMap;
    this.googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // this line shows the current location button
    googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
    Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
}
```

Comment: ,you are right but the problem is that when i am writing the above code in onMapReady and trying to go to another location then it is taking me to another location and withing miliseconds it is getting me back to the current location without doing anything.

Comment: Are you using any location listener to get the location updates?

Comment: I am using getLastKnownLocation and onLocationChanged.

Comment: Please share your onLocationChanged

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Deepak..Problem is solved by removing    googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener) from onMapReady.

Comment: Yes this is the culprit.
You are welcome :) Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by removing googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeList‌​ener) from onMapReady